# Install blackberry plugin in Titanium studio OsX

Tags: plugins, blackberry, titanium, appcelerator

i have a huge problem since yesterday!!

i have installed titanium studio,it runs with android and iphone.
I know it does not support blackberry yet, but is there a workaround that let me build app using the blackberry plugin?

If so, can anyone guide me to a tutorial on installing the BB plugin in titanium?

I tried to follow [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/blackberry/getting-started-beta-preview) and [this](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/BlackBerry+Support) with no success:

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just needed to be registered as minimum with indie account !!

Answer (score 1):

You might notice that in the second link, near the top of the page it states "Currently, BlackBerry development is enabled on Windows OS only." This is because we (Appcelerator) dont support beta software, and the only non-beta version of the BlackBerry emulator (provided by BlackBerry) is windows only. This emulator is required to do any kind of BlackBerry development.

Comment: the first link states that `Technically speaking, you can develop and build your Blackberry applications on any platform supported by Titanium (Windows, Mac OS X or Linux), but you will not be able to test them in the Blackberry simulator on any platform other than Windows.`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the blackberry OSX plugin requires "rosetta" to install on OSX so the installer will not work on later versions of the operating system